# I can't get list of all uwb estimote beacons when we enter in beacon range android

Tags: android, beacon, estimote, uwb

Here is my code

I have 3 beacons on cloud estimote account. All 3 beacons put on some distance with same floor but i can't get all beacon details when I enter in beacon range area.
please help me what is wrong with my code.

```
private void beaconRegionConfig() {

    BeaconRegion beaconRegion = new BeaconRegion("", null, null, null);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000, 30000);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(10000, 5000);

    beaconManager.connect(() -> {
        beaconManager.startRanging(beaconRegion);
        beaconManager.setConfigurableDevicesListener(configurableDevices -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "configurableDevicesList =  " + configurableDevices);
        
        });
    
    });


    // Set up ranging for get all beacons
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.BeaconRangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(BeaconRegion region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            // Handle discovered beacons here
            //Log.e(TAG, "region: " + region);
            Log.e(TAG, "region " + region + " , _beaconsSize: " + beacons.size() + " ," + beacons);
        }
    });
 
}
```

I Get o/p like this

```
_beaconsSize: 1 ,[Beacon{macAddress=[F0:1A:A0:11:D5:A8], 
proximityUUID=5861636c-716e-2301-be01-6c731222f008, major=1, 
  minor=0, measuredPower=-53, rssi=-102}]
```

In menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- for beacons-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
```

In gradle

```
  implementation 'com.estimote:sdk:1.0.12'
```

This 3 beacons in my estomote cloud account

```
ice
Identifier: a7....
Tags:IceTag
Packets:None
Location:385,..., India

lemon
Identifier:79.....
Tags:LemonTag
Packets:None
Location:385,..., India

caramel
Identifier:db....
Tags:Test
Packets:None
Location: 385, ...,India
```